# Tint color of image not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a menu bar made with collection view. Each cell contains a image (png format)

I tried to set the tint in code as shown below but the tint color of icon is not changing.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MenuCell *cell = [collectionView
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.cell
                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    cell.menuCellIcon.image = [UIImage
                               imageNamed:[self.menuCellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] ];
    [cell.menuCellIcon.image
     imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

    cell.menuCellIcon.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
...
```

Comment: try changing the rendering mode as original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line... `[cell.menuCellIcon.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];`

Returns a new image that uses rendering mode template. You are currently not doing anything with the result of this code.

You should fix your code like this...

```
cell.menuCellIcon.image = [[UIImage 
                           imageNamed:self.menuCellImages[indexPath.item]] 
                           imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Also, use the new syntax for accessing arrays. `objectAtIndex` is a very old syntax :)

Comment: @ios the new syntax is like in my answer. `array[0]` for example. Instead of `[array objectAtIndex:0]` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write this way

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.menuCellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] ];
cell.menuCellIcon.image =   [image
     imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

cell.menuCellIcon.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not use the `UIImage` that is returned from this line:

```
[cell.menuCellIcon.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

You should use the following syntax:

```
cell.menuCellIcon.image = [UIImage
                          imageNamed: [self.menuCellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]                             
                          imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
```